# Nomad job issue. "tls verification failed x509 certificate signed by unknown authority"

Tags: ssl, docker, nomad

I'm trying to start nomad job with docker driver, it should pull an image from my local docker registry. I've used tls certififcate issued by Nomad tls cert create, docker works fine with it. But when I try to run my job I get the following error "tls verification failed x509 certificate signed by unknown authority".

I've also tried to use certificates issued by Vault, same problem. And tried to add this certificate to trusted certificates at the OS level, which also had no result.

Here is a part of my job.hcl file

```
   task "frontend" {
   driver = "docker"
   config {
    image = "https://167.235.72.131/frontend"
    ports = ["http", "https"]
  }
```